# Processing multiple queries in Talend open studio

Tags: oracle, postgresql, etl, talend

Is it possible to process multiple queries in  tOracleInput palette in Talend, If yes, how ? If no then what palette should I use to do the same ? The goal is to update a flag to 0 in oracle after it is moved to Postgres using Talend.

After changes. Here is the result:
[image: After changes.Here is the result]

Comment: Why you dont use two component for each operation ?

Comment: I tried, it gets the job done but still I get errors on canvas with red ink. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Add a well described screen shot of your job please.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: some exception and jdbc driver errors

Comment: Of course to be able to help we need the *exact exception/jdbc error text*.

Comment: have you tried tOracleRow ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to use multiple queries in *one* tOracleInput component. It seems to me you would need to add a *tOracleOutput* to update the field after you inserted the data with a *tPostgresOutput* component and no error occured.

Comment: Is it possible to add Update query(user defined) in tOraclOutpu component ? If yes, could you please tell me the steps

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. It is possible to create a SQL statement and run it against the database with *tOracleRow*. Also, you could change the flag with a tMap and use a tOracleOutput, which would be the preferred way.

Comment: Did you read any tutorials on Talend before? It seems to me that those questions will go away if you will walk through a few tutorials which show data preparation.